# Algorithm for Graph generation from the degree sequence?

Tags: graph-theory

Given the degree sequence, is there an algorithm that can return a graph G which satisfies the degree sequence?

There can be more than one graph available for a degree sequence. It is enough if the algorithm returns only one of them.

Assume: Undirected graph, no weights, not a multi-graph(only one edge between 2 vertices).

Comment: Invalidity checks:   
1. Sum of degrees is even (undirected)
2. Each degree < n 

Are there any more invalidity checks i can deduce from the degree sequence input?

Comment: googling gave me "Havel-Hakimi theorem".. Which i am not sure gives the required output.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_%28graph_theory%29#Degree_sequence) Wikipedia section and the first paper available [here](http://web.cse.msu.edu/~cse835/Papers/); you can also search on 'Hakimi-Havel algorithm'.

Answer (score 0):

The degree sequence algorithm that I am speaking of is as follows:
(1) Start with the terms of the sequence in decreasing order,
(2) Remove the largest term, m, and reduce the next m terms by one, and
(3) rearrange the new sequence in decreasing order.

Proving this however is more of a challenge.